# Site Title/Header for Wordpress Blog

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want the title of my blog to appear as one thing while its on the homepage, and something else when it is everywhere else on my blog.

Does this code look right?

```
<title>
<?php 
if ( is_home() )
   echo "Blog Title" //When on the homepage
else
   echo ucwords(wp_title('',true)); //Name of blog article
   echo ucwords(get_bloginfo('name')); //Followed by site name
?>
</title>
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one thing you should pass `false` in the `wp_title` function

`echo ucwords(wp_title('',false));`

wp_title function echo the title if the second argument is passed as true, if it is passed false it will return the title for further operations

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your functions are working and retrieving the correct data, that code is perfectly acceptable for what you're using it for.